# How to Disable a particular Intent-filter programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a SplashScreen with 3 Intent-filters defined in Manifest like this -

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="kljb"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="kljb"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:host="xyz"
                    android:scheme="abc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want to disable this one -

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:host="xyz"
                    android:scheme="abc" />
            </intent-filter>
```

And After some user Action, I want to Enable it.

I have tried using -

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ".SplashScreen");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I don't know exactly where to write this above code. I set this code in the oncreate of the SplashScreen but getting the error -

**Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
 java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to change component state;**

I know this question has been asked a number of times on SO but none of them is about where to write this code.

After Commonsware Suggestion:

I made an alias -

```
<activity-alias
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:targetActivity=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:host="xyz"
                    android:scheme="abc" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity-alias>
```

So I am calling the code in the oncreate() of the MainActivity which opens after the SplashScreen -

> 2019-10-06 04:49:52.578 23014-23014/com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.debug
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.debug, PID: 23014
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.debug/com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to change component state;
>   pid=23014, uid=10262, component=com.khaalijeb.inkdrops/.SplashScreen
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to change component state; pid=23014, uid=10262,
>   component=com.khaalijeb.inkdrops/.SplashScreen
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
>           at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:7336)
>           at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2554)
>           at com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1604)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>        Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
>           at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21250)
>           at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setComponentEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21184)
>           at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3473)
>           at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4015)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)

This is the same error I was getting.

Comment: That code would disable your entire activity, which presumably is not what you want. You need to separate that `<intent-filter>` out into an `<activity-alias>`, then disable that alias using your code snippet. With regards to your crash, you might consider editing your question showing the complete stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have made an edit based on your suggestion. I created an alias with the desired intent-filter in it and rest is in the original Activity. Check the stacktrace.

Comment: Change the `android:name` of the alias to something unique. Do not name it the same as the activity. Then, change your `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to refer to the alias' name.

Comment: Done that already. Still getting the error. I am in debug mode so when I set getpackage() in new component name () I get splashscreen is not defined in mypwckagename.debug

Comment: So I changed the getpackage and set my original package name without the debug prefix. With this I am not getting the "activity not defined" error but that error mentioned is still there.

Comment: Is writing the above code in oncreate() seems good??

Comment: I do not know why you are getting this error message at this point, sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200463/discussion-between-sniper-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

So, I came to realize after a day of debugging and looking into the [Android Developers' Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName) about the ComponentName.

I was implementing it in the debug mode and my packageName is - **applicationId + suffix.**
as you can see yours in **build.gradle**.

Previously, I was doing something like

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(this, getPackageName() + ".AliasSplashScreen");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Now you see that I was using get package name() which is different for each build but My Class name has no effect due to this.

My class Name is and will always be **originalpackagename.classname** or more clearly **applicationid.className.** no matter the build variant(debug or release).

The Correct way is -

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(this, applicationid + ".AliasSplashScreen");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

And as CommonsWare pointed out you have to create an `activity-alias` in Android Manifest keeping the original one and `targetActivity` should be the one whose alias you are creating with the desired `intent-filter` inside that and use the above code to disable it in the onCreate() of the Next Activity and to enable it use **`PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`**